# Install a package manager on a terramaster NAS

Tags: linux, package-management

I got this NAS and while it has a decent amount of features, I was hoping i could extend them a bit.

It's running a dual core Celeron with 2gb of ram. I tried to find the Linux distro, but it seems it's a custom made one by the company called 'TOS'.

```
[root@NAS /]# lsb_release -a
-bash: lsb_release: command not found
```

Checking the kernel didnt help much either:

```
[root@NAS /]# uname -a
Linux NAS 4.0.0 #207 SMP Tue Jul 19 12:22:50 CST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It has no gcc compiler either, so I am very limited in options.

[image: This is pretty much what i have available]

Other than chroot I can't think of anything else I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for the GPL components used on TerraMaster NAS devices [is apparently available](https://sourceforge.net/projects/terramaster-gpl-source/files/TNAS%20X86%20GPL%20source/), so you could poke around that to figure out what C library is used etc. and thus replicate a build environment elsewhere that could produce compatible libraries and binaries. Then you could use a “package manager” designed to work in situations where it doesn’t control the complete system, something like [Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/stow.html) perhaps.

But in your situation I suspect the simplest solution *is* a `chroot`-based approach, *e.g.* using [Debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap): download the tarball from [the `debootstrap` package page](https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/debootstrap) ([version 1.0.87](http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/d/debootstrap/debootstrap_1.0.87.tar.gz) currently), extract it on the NAS, create a directory for the distribution, and run it from the extracted directory (see the `README` file in the tarball for details):

```
mkdir /debian-stable
export DEBOOTSTRAP_DIR=`pwd`
./debootstrap stable /debian-stable
```

Someone has apparently [managed to run Gentoo on the NAS](http://forum.nas-central.org/viewtopic.php?f=299&t=16601), so it might well be possible to completely replace the system software with your distribution of choice — but that might not be advisable...

Comment: I have no idea how you found that information, i've been searching for a few days now! Thank you for the advice. I'll see if i can do something with the source, they have *some* way of managing packages as the user interface allows me to do it to a limited extent. I see it's running nginx and php-fpm so it's a js frontend with a php api, if i find the code i should be able to see how they do it.

Comment: To second @Stephen Kitt's answer: `./debootstrap --arch=amd64 stable /debian-stable http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian` is what worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

I have the Terra-master F2-420 NAS.  I've never loaded TOS on it.  I just placed a Linux bootable hard disk drive (fedora 25/26) in it and it booted directly from that drive. The external drive slots show as sda and sdb and some internal flash shows as sdc.  I have made no effort to use sdc.  I have not encountered any issues with it.